# What do the different "Incoming LAN Connections" settings mean in TeamViewer?

Tags: networking, teamviewer

In TeamViewer there are 3 settings under

Network Settings -> Incoming LAN Connections:

1. deactivated
2. accept
3. accept exclusively

I tried searching Google and TeamViewer sites but couldn't find an explanation.

Can anyone explain what each means?

Comment: which version of TeamViewer you are using?

Comment: latest version - 11

Answer (score 5):

Just hover over the setting and it will give you the required information.

It states:

> Enables direct connections within a Local Area Network. This is useful for users without access to the internet or solely offering support in Local Area Network.

Using this option You can establish Remote control sessions on your local network directly by using IP addresses or computer names. i.e.  use TeamViewer without the internet in LAN.

Refer to KB: [Use TeamViewer in LAN](https://community.teamviewer.com/kb/articles/4618)

The explanation for options:

1. **deactivated** : LAN access is deactivated, will only attempt to use internet.
2. **accept** : This option will accept connections from LAN and internet.
3. **accept exclusively** : Will not connect via internet and is accessible exclusively through IP on LAN. Note: "Your ID" will change to your local IP.

---

[image: TeamViewer 9.0.4]
<sub>TeamViewer 9.0.4 Sceenshot</sub>

Comment: There is no mouse-over hint on Linux